# iText Command Line - Version 5.5.2

Tags: itext

I currently use iText 1.3 run from a command line generated in a COBOL program to concatenate PDF documents.
I'm attempting to update to iText 5.5.2 at the moment, but the command line has, obviously, changed with time.
Can anyone inform me of the format this now requires?
Or where I can find this information, because it doesn't appear on the iText Website as far as I can see.

Thanks

Comment: iText is a Java library. Names of packages, classes and methods have changed over time of course, same as method signatures. But without knowing which classes and methods you are invoking from your COBOL program, it'll be hard to point you to their current counter-parts.

Comment: However, the most obvious change that happened in the course of 1.3 to 5.5.2 is the renaming of the root package, from `com.lowagie` to `com.itextpdf`.